# Мертвые срама не имут

Tags: этимология, фонетика

Вот попалось такое интересное выражение: "мертвые срама не имут".

Появились связанные с ним вопросы.

1. Каково происхождение этого выражения?
2. Как правильно его произнести? Наверное, все-таки скорее "не и́мут", чем "не иму́т"
3. "имут" - это форма какого слова? Не однокоренное ли с "иметь"? А почему тогда форма такая странная?

Прошу помочь разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: > 1. Каково происхождение этого выражения?

Это сказал киевский князь Святослав в Х веке перед неравной битвой. Русских воинов было меньше, чем противников, византийцев.

Полностью фраза выглядит приблизительно так: **"Да не посрамим земли Русския, но ляжем костьми тут: бо мертвые срама не имут."**

Князь хотел, чтобы воины не допустили позорного разгрома русского войска, а предпочли геройскую смерть в бою подчинению противнику. Византия проиграла эту битву Руси.

Comment: Угу...
Одно маленькое замечание. 
Это был набег на Византию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это искажённое выражение из Повести Временных Лет. Описывается воззвание князя Святослава к воинам, в котором он призывает, что лучше умереть, чем сдаться   «видѣвъ же Русь и оубоӕшасѧ зѣл̑. множьства вои и реч̑ Ст҃ославъ. оуже намъ нѣкамо сѧ дѣти. и волею и нєволєю стати противу. да нє посрамим земли Рускиє. но лѧземы костью ту. и **мр҃тьвы бо сорома нє имаєть**. ащє ли побѣгнємъ то срамъ нам̑ . и нє имамъ оубѣгнути. но станємъ крѣпко. азъ же предъ вами поиду. ащє моӕ глава лѧжеть. тоже промыслитє ѡ себѣ. и ркоша вои идєже глава твоӕ лѧжеть. ту и главы наша сложим.

Ударение на первый слог "не Имут".

На современном языке фраза звучит как - "Некуда нам деться, надо биться - волею или неволей. Не посрамим земли Русской, но ляжем здесь костьми, ибо мёртвые позора не имеют  Если же побежим - будет нам позор. Так не побежим же, но встанем крепко. Я буду впереди вас. Если паду я тоже и для себя готовте. И сказали воины - "Где твоя голова ляжет, там и мы головы наши сложим."

Answer (score 2):

Пословица "мертвые сраму не Имут" употребляется в двух значениях: 1) смерть в бою всегда почетна; 2) (редко употребляется в этом значении) о мертвых можно говорить только хорошее, мертвых осуждать нельзя. Происхождение пословицы таково: это слова, с которыми, по свидетельству летописца, князь Святослав обратился к своим воинам перед битвой с византийцами в 970 г.   под городом Доростол (сейчас болгарский город Силистрия): Да не посрамим земли Русская, поляжем костьми тут - мертвый бо срама не имут.
И’мут - 3 л. мн. от устар. глаг. яти "взять".

Тема, конечно, интересная. Спасибо за  вопрос.

Comment: Имут - от роського - имати - иметь, владеть.  В сегодняшнем талышском языке-"ими" -владей, имей.

Answer (score 2):

1. Это выражение приписывают князю Святославу Игоревичу.  Датируют приблизительно 970г. В летописи сказано, что князь Святослав перед битвой с византийцами дал такое наставление своим воинам: «Нам некуда уже деться, хотим мы или не хотим — должны сражаться. Так не посрамим земли Русской, но ляжем здесь костьми, ибо мертвые сраму не имут. Если же побежим — позор нам будет. Так не побежим же, но станем крепко, а я пойду впереди вас: если моя голова ляжет, то о своих сами позаботьтесь.». http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Битва_при_Аркадиополе_(970)#section_3
2. Имут правильно, http://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/мёртвые_сраму_не_имут
3. Имут - это форма от глагола "иметь".  Старослав. "имѣти"

Comment: Пока писАла, уже все ответили :))))))

Comment: Надо заранее готовиться!)))

Comment: <И́МУТ> - 3 л. мн.ч. от устар. глаг. яти( "взять") - имати.Сначала он спрягался по нетематическому классу и имел форму Имут, потом это спряжение утратилось, глагол перешёл в 3 тематический класс, стал выглядеть как "имают", затем фонетические изменения привели к "имеют". Но в диалектах сейчас есть и имают именно в первом значении "брать, хватать".

Comment: Это все здорово. Но почему в ответе @Марк Из дана форма "имаєть"? Насколько я понимаю, это примерно двенадцатый век. Т.е. получается, что форма "имаєть" более древняя? А когда тогда произошло это искажение ("имаєть"->"имут")?

Comment: @gecube это форма из Ипатьевского сборника, древнейший список которой датируют XV веком, а создана в кон. XIII-нач. XIV века.

В Лаврентьевской летописи (Рукопись 1377 года) фраза звучит - "Да не посрамимъ землѣ Рускıѣ . но лѧжемъ костьми [ту] И мертвъı . ибо срама не имамъ . аще ли побѣгнемъ срамъ имамъ . и не имамъ оубѣжати но станемъ крѣпко".

Comment: @Марк Из, но все равно я там "и́мут" не вижу, как ни стараюсь увидеть. PS: Ок. Увидел. Просто нужно было этот самый "Ипатьевский сборник" посмотреть самолично. Но все равно форма "имут" там используется в другом месте. А в конкретной обсуждаемой фразе - "мр҃тьвы бо сорома нє имаєть". [Ссылка][1]

[1]:http://litopys.org.ua/ipatlet/ipat04.htm

Comment: Считайте это современной адаптацией, ведь крылатое выражение широко используется, роман Бакланова с таким названием есть, надо сделать скидку на приближение...

Comment: Это не современная адаптация. о склонении др-р. глаголов:
http://window.edu.ru/library/pdf2txt/112/22112/5339/page7
К нетематическим (V класс) относилось всего пять глаголов:
быти, дати, hсти ‘кушать’, вhдhти ‘знать’ и имати.
 Мн. число:1 л.. ~смъ дамъ вhмъ ıамъ имамъ.
 Мн.ч.:3 л. с@ть дад#ть вhд#ть ıад#ть им@ть(имуть).В др.-р. мягк. оконч., в ст.-слав. -  твёрдое:имутъ. А в глаг. 3 класса - с [j]. Вот когда перешёл глагол в 3 класс, появилось и -jут.В разных текстах разный перевод.Может, там это слово было не в 3, а в 1 л., поэтому имамъ.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то это переосмысленное выражение из книги пророка Иеремии: "Стыдятся ли они, совершая мерзость? И стыдиться не стыдятся и срама не имут. За это падут они среди павших, споткнутся в день расплаты, – сказал Господь". Иеремия, гл.8, стих 12.

Answer (score 0):

Имати-получать,добывать,обладать.,составной из ИМ,ям,ем,йом..-все, что применительно к себе..и ЯТИ,ять,еть,ать-взять,брать,совершать действие.Здесь основной корень-ИМ-применительно к себе,восходит к основополагающему звуку-Мъ-,что означал в древности-мое,меня,мне,я сам.В противовес корню-ИМъ,спользовался корень-ИНъ-все,что со стороны,не касаемо меня,из вне ..с основной-Нъ-звук обозначающий-отрицание,не желание,отторжение,исходящее из вне.